# NetworkManager not working on properly RasPi 3

Tags: pi-3, ethernet, networkmanager

I'm testing NetworkManager using 2 keyfile: 
one keyfile for the wired connection and one keyfile for the wireless connection.

- The setup works great on Raspberry Pi 1 and Raspberry pi 2.
- On Raspberry Pi 3 is behaving incorrectly.
- I'm doing my tests by moving the very same SD card with the very same OS on it from one raspberry to another.

On Pi 3 the behavior is the following:

- If the Raspberry is booted up WITH the ethernet cable connected and then after the boot I unplug the cable, the status of the ethernet connection remains connected and there is no way to make it change state.
- On the other hand if the Raspberry is booted up WITHOUT the ethernet cable connected and after the boot i plug it in/out repeatedly, the state of the connection follows accordingly.

The keyfile `ethernet`:

```
[connection]
id=ethernet
uuid=60d17e82-1be7-3d0f-b924-e980be41fcba
type=ethernet

[ipv6]
method=ignore

[ipv4]
method=auto
```

What should I look into? ethernet driver? I'm really lost here.

**UPDATE:**
I also tried to use NetworkManager with ifupdown plugin instead of keyfile plugin.

Here the `eth0` interface file:

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

The behavious is exactly the same:

- If I boot up the RasPi 3 with cable disconnected everything works perfect.
- If I boot up the RasPi 3 with cable connected NetworkManager doesn't recognize the cable disconnection event.

Comment: A "it doesn't work" question without detail of what you did is unanswerable. While it is possible to use NetworkManager on Raspbian it is unlikely you would find anyone who uses it.

Comment: My question is answerable and as a matter of fact the solution has been found by reviewing the behavior of the kernel driver used by the raspberry PI 3 (LAN78XX).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out this was the issue.

There is an issue with the current version of the ethernet driver:

https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1100

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.